# Kotlin - Issue in getting milliseconds for Time passed

Tags: android, kotlin, time, datetime-format, milliseconds

I have created below method to get the milliseconds from 12 hour format time :

```
fun getMillisecondsFromTime(time: String): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh aa")
    formatter.isLenient = false

    val oldDate = formatter.parse(getLocaleTime(time,"hh aa"))
    val oldMillis = oldDate.time
    return "" + oldMillis
}
```

I am calling this method as below for four different times:

```
var strTime1:String = DateUtils.getMillisecondsFromTime("1 PM")//13 * 3600
var strTime2:String = DateUtils.getMillisecondsFromTime("2 PM")//14 * 3600
var strTime3:String = DateUtils.getMillisecondsFromTime("1 AM")//1 * 3600
var strTime4:String = DateUtils.getMillisecondsFromTime("2 AM")//2 * 3600
```

Result am getting is wrong. i.e. for **1 PM** milliseconds should be **48600** But, am getting :

1 PM >>>>>: 45000000, should be **48600**

2 PM >>>>>: 48600000, should be **50400**

What might be the issue?

**EDIT**  : getting local time as below :

```
fun getLocaleTime(date: String, timeFormat: String): String {

    val df = SimpleDateFormat(timeFormat, Locale.ENGLISH)
    df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    val date = df.parse(date)
    df.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
    val formattedDate = df.format(date)
    return formattedDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get hours of the day using Calendar. And then multiply it with 3600. Like

```
fun getMillisecondsFromTime(time: String): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh aa")
    formatter.isLenient = false

    val oldDate = formatter.parse(getLocaleTime(time,"hh aa"))
    // val oldMillis = oldDate.time

    val cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = oldDate
    val hourIn24Format = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)

    return "" + (hourIn24Format * 3600)
}
```

*Your current code is returning time in millies from milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT to the time you gave as input.*

---

***Note:***

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in this way, but this seems not a good way. If you can explain more about your requirements, I or any other can guide you for better ways.

Comment: I have static list for timings cnotains 1 PM, 2 PM, 3 PM. and not have to take current time. It's list of 12Hour time format. wihch I need to convert to milliseconds.

Comment: I have checked, It's returning 64800 instead of 48600(13*3600) for 1 PM..!

Comment: Let me check. I think It is taking 1 hour extra

Comment: It's 12 hour format, need is to take 12 hour format time to millis.

Comment: @JaiminModi I got what you are saying. 24 hour format is needed for your output, as you are using 13 for 1PM. Share code for getLocalTime()

Comment: Please check edited the code. Added function to get local time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208826/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-jaimin-modi).